# Syntax error when modifying pandas dataframe object

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a csv file test.csv.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

In [0]

```
df = pd.read_csv('pandas/test.csv')
```

In [1]

```
df.columns
```

Out [0]

```
Index(['local_date', 'local_time','Latitude',
           'Longitude','SourceID','Vge','PacketClass'],
      dtype='object') 



df['Type'] = if MAN in df['Class'] return 'MAN' else return 'MAIN'
```

I am getting a syntax error `^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

What is the way to create a new column inside a dataframe as above in a single line.

Answer (score 2):

The `return` statement can only be used in functions.

Rewrite:

```
df['Type'] = 'MAN' if MAN in df['Class'] else 'MAIN'
```